# PHPExcel - Getting irrelevant value in MySQL

Tags: php, phpexcel

Whenever I import an excel file into MySQL using PHPExcel then I don't get some values and also values get inserted into irrespective columns.

BUT when I use echo for showing excel file then it shows exact report.

Also, I want only few selected columns to be imported from 10-15 columns.

Thanks in advance

**My Code**

```
<?php
    //include the following 2 files
    require 'C:\xampp\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'C:\xampp\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("invoice",$conn);

$file=$_POST['file'];
$srow=$_POST['srow'];



$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
    echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
    echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
}



echo 'Data: <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
for ($row = $srow; $row <= $highestRow-1; ++ $row) {
   echo '<tr>';
   for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
       $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
       $val = $cell->getValue();
       if($row === 1)
            echo '<td style="background:#000; color:#fff;">' . $val . '</td>';
       else
           echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
   }
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';




for ($row = $srow; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    $val=array();
for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
   $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $srow);
$val[] = $cell->getValue();

}
$dropdownval=$_POST['menu'];

if ($dropdownval!='none')
{
$sql="INSERT INTO $dropdownval(`Bkng Date`,`ID Number`,`Pax Name`,`Ticket Number`,`PNR`,`Sector`,`Travel Date`,`Basic`,`Tax`,`Net Payable`)
VALUES('".$val[1]."','".$val[2]."','".$val[3]."','" .$val[4]."','".$val[5]."','".$val[6]."','".$val[7]."','".$val[8]."','".$val[9]."','".$val[10]."')";
mysql_query($sql)or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_query($sql))
    echo "Successfully Uploaded ".$file;
    else
        echo "Error while uploading ".$file;
    //echo $sql."\n";
}

else
    {
    $tname=$_POST['tname'];
$createTable="CREATE TABLE $tname(
 `Bkng Date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `ID Number` INT NOT NULL ,
 `Pax Name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Ticket Number` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
 `PNR` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Sector` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `Travel Date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `Basic` DECIMAL NOT NULL ,
 `Tax` DECIMAL NOT NULL ,
 `Net Payable` DECIMAL NOT NULL)";
mysql_query($createTable);

$sql1="INSERT INTO $tname(`Bkng Date`,`ID Number`,`Pax Name`,`Ticket Number`,`PNR`,`Sector`,`Travel Date`,`Basic`,`Tax`,`Net Payable`)
VALUES('".$val[1]."','".$val[2]."','".$val[3]."','" .$val[4]."','".$val[5]."','".$val[6]."','".$val[7]."','".$val[8]."','".$val[9]."','".$val[10]."')";
    mysql_query($sql1)or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        if(mysql_query($sql1))
    echo "Table $tname has been created...Successfully Uploaded ".$file;
    else
        echo "Error while uploading ".$file;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: This is typically caused by values containing quotes and the like, which you would have to escape correctly. Using bound variables instead of constructing the values part like you do avoids this problem.

Comment: If you only want columns 10 to 15, then change `for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col)` to `for ($col = 10; $col <= 15; ++ $col)`

Comment: Suppose I want only columns 1,2,4,7,10...I mean any random columns then ?